# Is there a ros1 package like demo_nodes_cpp from ros2?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just need a simple talker/listener pair to use for demo purposes. Yes I could roll my own, but for testing connectivity a standard package is a little easier.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389097/is-there-a-ros1-package-like-demo_nodes_cpp-from-ros2?/) by [rkent](https://answers.ros.org/users/55154/rkent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2021-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK I found, roscpp_tutorials has a talker and listener

---

Originally posted by [rkent](https://answers.ros.org/users/55154/rkent/) with karma: 20 on 2021-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-21**:
For future readers: you can install it using `apt install ros-noetic-roscpp-tutorials`.

Similar for `rospy`: `ros-noetic-rospy-tutorials`.

And you could even opt to just use `rostopic pub` and `rostopic echo`.